# Vba code for copy paste

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with a vba code logical statement 
I have a worksheet1 where c19 is start date and d19 is end date. 
There is another sheet whose column f contains a series of dates. 
I need to pick up dates from column f which are greater than equal to start date and less than equal to end date and then copy paste the dates in worksheet1 say range c25

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read the [ask] page and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, though I have kept the input range as only F1 to F12 instead of the entire F column

```
Sub copy_paste()

Dim cell As Range, paste_loc As Range

Set paste_loc = Range("C25") 'Output paste location

For Each cell In Range("F1:F12")    'Input range

    If cell.Value > Range("C19").Value And cell.Value < Range("C19").Value Then
        paste_loc = cell.Value
        Set paste_loc = paste_loc.Offset(1, 0)
    End If

Next cell


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas but I feel I didn't explain my need well have posted another question.please help